# How can I dynamically combine data frames with different column names in R?

Tags: r

I have an analytics script that processes batches of data with similar structure, but different column names. I need to preserve the column names for later ETL scripts, but we want to do do some processing, e.g,:

```
results <- data.frame();
for (name in names(data[[1]])) {   
    # Start by combining each column into a single matrix
    working <- lapply(data, function(item)item[[name]]);
    working <- matrix(unlist(working), ncol = 50, byrow = TRUE);

    # Dump the data for the archive
    write.csv(working, file = paste(PATH, prefix, name, '.csv', sep = ''), row.names = FALSE);

    # Calculate the mean and SD for each year, bind to the results
    df <- data.frame(colMeans(working), colSds(working));
    names(df) <- c(paste(name, '.mean', sep = ''), paste(name, '.sd', sep = ''));

    # Combine the working df with the processing one
}
```

Per the last comment in the example, how can I combine data frames? I've tried `rbind` and `rbind.fill` but neither work and their may be 10's to 100's of different column names in the data files.

Comment: Can you post some data that we can use to reproduce your error?  Because on my computer I created two dummy data frames with different column names, and `rbind.fill` works well.

Comment: @nsinghs I suspect the column names are causing the problem. You can almost just generate a bunch of random values for columns c(‘A’, ‘B’, ..., ‘Z’) and it is similar to the files. When I ran rbind.fill the first two columns where fine (e.g., ‘A.mean’, ‘A.sd’) but the rest where NA for the data. However, checking during execution showed valid data generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have been more of an issue with searching for the right keyword, but the `cbind` method was actually the way to go along with a matrix,

```
# Allocate for the number of rows needed
results <- matrix(nrow = rows)

for (name in names(data[[1]])) {   
    # Data processing

    # Append the results to the working data
    results <- cbind(results, df)   
}

# Drop the first placeholder column created upon allocation
results <- results[, -1];
```

Obviously the catch is that the columns need to have the same number of rows, but otherwise it is just a matter of appending the columns to the matrix.